# Sending keystrokes to an unfocused process pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm trying to send keystrokes of regular keyboard input from 'a-z' which may or may not include the directional arrow keys to a running game process, however i'm confused at the pywinauto documentation:

I've already connected the existing process via pid by:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys    
app = Application().connect(process=1234)
#app.SendKeys('a')? Doesn't seem to work
```

I've read some other answers on this but it's not very clear as to what the next step is on the documentation, there aren't any real examples.

I've also read from some other answers that SendKeys auto focuses the windows, which isn't want I want, if possible would it be possible to send keystrokes to the process silently?

Answer (score 1):

There are few moments. If the game process has its own window with native handle, you may try the following:

```
 app.window(title="Window title").send_keystrokes("something")
 app.window(title="Window title").send_chars("something")
```

It should work even for minimized window. The difference may appear for special symbols which may not work for some of these methods or even for both. But arrows should probably work with `send_keystrokes`.

If it's DirectX game, sending keys might be more complicated task. A while ago I found some references about potential implementation of this: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/469 Though I had no chance to try it yet.

Comment: Tried both of the proposed solutions, which neither work as it raises "pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:" I've just typed the image name in place of "Window title" from the windows shell command 'tasklist'.

I am not sure whether the game has DX dependencies, the game is pretty old so I assume so, it is 'MapleStory' (old version release dated back to ~2006-10)

Comment: Okay, maybe `app.top_window().send_chars("...")` would help?

Comment: Unfortunately not